# Connecting from DMZ machine to Server 2003 on a domain?

Tags: active-directory, dmz, windows-server-2003

We have a web server on a DMZ that needs to read/write to a single file location on our Server 2003 Domain.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Read / write using what protocol(s)?  Windows share?  FTP?...

Comment: Depends on the requirements, it would be better to schedule data pickup from the server using some scheduled script FROM the internal network. In essence, don't allow access from within the DMZ to the internal LAN.

Comment: @Squillman - I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Vick - Scheduled pickup might work ... however, if for some reason we needed to access it directly, any suggestions?

Comment: @Jess - Lock down the firewall to allow access ONLY one specific machine, create a LOCAL username on that server and allow access to only one specific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the requirements, it would be better to schedule data pickup from the server using some scheduled script FROM the internal network. In essence, don't allow access from within the DMZ to the internal LAN.

Answer (score 1):

You could use webdav over ssl giving only the computer account access to the file. Using webdav you can map a drive to the SSL location of the server.

Of course there are still other things to take into account like firewall configs, what you do with the file (if anything) when you download it locally, if the machine's are both members of the same domain (or trusted), etc.